# SQL change value, to the next row of another table

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have the next table structure, table A:

```
| id |
|----|
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 7  |
```

Table B:

```
| id | title | last_id |
|----|-------|---------|
| 1  |   a   |    1    |
| 2  |   b   |    2    |
| 3  |   c   |    3    |
```

I want to change **Table's B** `last_id` to the next matching `id` from **Table A**.

Example: (Referring to **Table's B first row**)

Current `last_id` is **1**, So I need to forward it's value to the next, **bigger id** from **Table A**.

So it will go:

`1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 7`

It can be done also with PHP, but maybe there is a way to keep it in the SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: The server runs MySQL.

Comment: And same for all the rows? I mean, all last_id on Table B at the end of the process will have value of 7 ?

Comment: Yes, that's the final result.

Comment: Which database server are you using? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Oracle? Something else?

Comment: MySQL, sorry I haven't pointed that out.

Comment: MySQL? Then I'm not sure that my answer will be correctly executed, I do not have too much experience on mysql, maybe the sintax will be different

Comment: There's almost no difference in what you provided, from the MySQL syntax, I am able to do those small changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous answer is correct, but the +1 I believe is no needed as you just need value 7

```
UPDATE table_b
   SET last_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_a)
```

Edited:

Now it picks the minimum value from table_a bigger that the last_id on table_b

```
UPDATE table_b
   SET last_id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_a WHERE id>last_id)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just set `last_id` to `7`, without going through 3 and 4?

Comment: Yes, that is what it would do. Is not that what you need at the end? Or maybe what you want is to print all the values?

Comment: I need a query, that each time you call it, for the selected row from `table B`, it will increase it's `last_id` to the next, bigger, `id`.

Comment: @GuyDavid But that's exactly what this does. It picks the largest `id` from `table_a` and updates the `last_id` column in `table_b` with that value. You would just need to add a `WHERE` clause to select the correct row in `table_b` to modify. Can you expand on your use case? I suspect that what you actually want here is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: The current query picks `7` at the first call. I need it to go through 3 and 4 before that.

Comment: @GuyDavid And what would it do with those values? Step through `table_b` and update each row sequentially?

Comment: edited...check if now it is ok, it will take minimum value from table_a but bigger than last_id

Comment: @Yaroslav Your edit has a hole in it - if there is no `id` in `table_a` that is larger than the current `last_id`, `last_id` will be set to `NULL`

Comment: @GuyDavid I'm starting to think it's stored procedure time here, there's no way to "loop" a table in a single query (AFAIK)

Comment: You accepted as answer, but remember what @DaveRandom pointed out, if no value is found, will return null. Adding a ISNULL or COALESCE should do the job, just a suggestion.

Comment: Yep, that's okay, since I can check for null, if the process is done, or I'll set it to 0 (an agreed number for operation completed). Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

**The following snippets are pseudo code.**

1. Grab the next **table_a** `id`:

   ```
   SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE id > $currentLastId ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
   ```
2. If not `null`, update your **table_b** `last_id` column.

**Example:** (Referring to **table_b** first row)

The SQL query would be:

```
SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

It would return `3`.